# How to prevent duplicates in database

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have been trying to prevent duplicates and get an error message to show up if a duplicated Email or Username (or both) has been typed, I wonder what's wrong with my code.

I have tried some of the solutions for similar problems, but they didn't seem to work. I am not sure if there is something wrong with my code or another way of doing it. It just runs and executes the code and the results gets added to the database, even if they are duplicated.

```
sqlCon.Open();

string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SSUser WHERE username=@username AND password=@password AND email=@email";
SqlCommand c1 = new SqlCommand(query);

SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("insert into SSUser values(@username, @password, @email)", sqlCon);
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", register_username.Text);
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", register_password.Text);
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", register_mail.Text);

SqlCommand check_username = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SSUser WHERE (username=@username) AND (email = @email)", sqlCon);

check_username.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", register_username.Text);
check_username.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", register_mail.Text);
int check = (int)check_username.ExecuteScalar();

if (check > 0)
{
    register_error.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    if (register_c.Text != register_password.Text)
    {
        register_error.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        c.ExecuteNonQuery();

        register_username.Text = "";
        register_password.Text = "";
        register_c.Text = "";
        register_mail.Text = "";
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the other solutions you tried that did not work?

Comment: I tried turning the columns of the username/email to Unique in the database which gave me another error which were an Exception. I also tried to set the primary key to the username/Email which gave me the same issue.

Comment: Your code should work. I will be very surprised if it is not working. Having said that, you should just check `username` and not password. Most likely you don't want more than 1 user with the same username regardless if their passwords are same or different.

Comment: You may use `if not exists .....  insert... ` or let the db take care of it by using unique constraints and then handle the exception when `insert...` is executed.

Comment: Also clean up your code so it's easier to read. Put all code for `c` in the else block because it's not needed anywhere else. And give it a good meaningful name such as `insertNewUserCommand`.

Comment: @allenking `if not exists ..... insert...` will pass whether user exists or not and the application will not be able to report to the user that the username exists already. His code should work.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies!~ I will be trying all the suggestions and will get back at you all asap.

Comment: Also what's the purpose of `c1`? Is that just another approach you had tried?

Comment: Yup, just as you said. Was just trying out stuff and the best way that they'd work.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Oh and also! Is there any reason/reasons that my code might not work? I mean I thought I wrote it right as well and I saw it working for other people online, I don't know what's wrong really. The whole exception thing might be a problem, I am trying it but not sure how good that will be

Comment: The exception route can work and there are cases where one might choose that route such as performance, less trip to db but only if that part of the code is the bottleneck. And you cannot just catch `SqlException` and decide it happened because of duplicates.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes, we can... why do you insist replying with this falsehood on every single post? The error code is 2627 whenever a primary key violation is thrown.

Comment: Your code should work and if it is not working, then you need to be more specific. Are you saying this part is not true when there are duplicates: `if (check > 0)`?

Comment: @kittoes0124 I never said we cannot. I said exception could be for many reasons. My exact point was that the check needs to be done. And the check needs to be in agreement with how you enforced this on the db side. If I did say such a thing then quote me and I will admit to my mistake. Otherwise, please delete your comment about "falsehood": No need to get personal here.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 It has to be in agreement because if the db side is enforced using a primary key, the application side will check for that violation. If unique on db side, then app needs to check that violation. If db side using custom exception, then app has to check for that error code. Yes I still stand by "how do you know what" and I never said inspecting is hard but simply to state that this must be communicated to the OP. So what don't I understand that I am spouting? I am noticing you cannot stay professional and resort to name calling; therefore, I will not reply to any of your messages.

Comment: @CodingYoshi That's not true though, and demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of how things work in this scenario. Both types of constraints throw the same error code; the string value might be different in each case but that's also why we don't depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Gordon Linoff's answer:
After you added the unique constraint to the appropriate attributes in your database you should be able to catch a SqlException:

```
try {
 c.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
}
```

Comment: And how do you know what caused the exception? It could be due to many reasons.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Easy, like so: `catch (SqlException e) { if (e.Number == 2627) { // violation of primary key detected } }`.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 that actually worked but gave me another error which I have been trying to fix, for some reason, when I use the Response.Redirect("Login.aspx") in the else statement it doesn't seem to work, is there any fix to that? It just doesn't load at all when I do it

Comment: @Wessam Hard to say without seeing your current code (try throwing it in a Gist and then post a link); there shouldn't be any good reason for the redirect to fail simply because it appeared in that else

Comment: @Kittoes0124   https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Wess977/5e260de52fcc87cfc9ff68c229a25b9f/raw/3ba797e5703c15263731cc77040c53be9f797bfa/code.exe

Here it is! The whole part in the else statement in the catch doesn't seem to be working for some reason. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Wessam Please add the method's signature as well (return type and parameters); hard for me to tell what the expected result is without it.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent duplicates, create unique constraints or indexes in the database:

```
alter table ssuser add constraint unq_ssuser_username unique (username);

alter table ssuser add constraint unq_ssuer_email unique (email);
```

Any insert or update that would create a duplicate will return an error.  You may want to catch the error when you attempt `insert`s and `update`s.

Comment: Yes! I have tried that, but catching the error wasn't really working. I mean, I probably was doing something wrong but any hints about catching the error?

Comment: Yes the db can/should enforce the uniqueness but one would have to be really careful catching such an exception and then deciding it was due to duplicate entry. The exception could be for a different reason. As for making it an index, I don't agree because everything unique doesn't need to be indexed.

Comment: @Wessam . . . `SQLException()`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: How does or the other answers possibly get downvotes?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know really! Someone has downvoted them...I am still experimenting to see how to make it work, I'll be updating this right after I'm done with that. Thanks for your efforts though!

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using your database layer for this; here is a working example of `T-SQL` that does exactly that:

```
create table [dbo].[SSUser] (
    [UserId] bigint not null identity (0, 1)
  , [UserName] nvarchar(255) not null
  , [Email] nvarchar(255) not null
  , [PasswordHash] varbinary(64) null
  , constraint [dbo_SSUser_Pk] primary key clustered ([UserName] asc) with (data_compression = page)
);
go

create type [dbo].[ISSUser] as table (
    [UserName] nvarchar(255) not null
  , [Email] nvarchar(255) not null
  , [PasswordHash] varbinary(64) null
  , primary key clustered ([UserName] asc)
);
go

create procedure [dbo].[usp_SSUser_Insert] (
    @users [dbo].[ISSUser] readonly
)
as
begin;
    set nocount on;
    set xact_abort on;

    insert into [dbo].[SSUser] (
        [UserName]
      , [Email]
      , [PasswordHash]
    )
    output [inserted].[UserId]
         , [inserted].[Email]
         , [inserted].[PasswordHash]
    select a.[UserName]
         , a.[Email]
         , a.[PasswordHash]
    from @users as a;
end;
```

And the accompanying `C#` code that'll call the procedure and trap any errors:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Koholint;Trusted_Connection=True;";
var userName = register_username.Text;
var email = register_mail.Text;
var passwordHash = register_password.HashBytes;

try {
    var tableMetadata = new[] {
        new SqlMetaData("UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255),
        new SqlMetaData("Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255),
        new SqlMetaData("PasswordHash", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 64),
    };
    var tableValues = new SqlDataRecord(tableMetadata);

    tableValues.SetValue(0, userName);
    tableValues.SetValue(1, email);
    tableValues.SetValue(2, passwordHash);

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = "[dbo].[usp_SSUser_Insert]";
        command.CommandTimeout = 15;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        var tableParameter = new SqlParameter("users", SqlDbType.Structured);

        tableParameter.TypeName = "[dbo].[ISSUser]";
        tableParameter.Value = new[] { tableValues };

        command.Parameters.Add(tableParameter);
        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            do {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt64(0)); // TODO: something more useful, or maybe nothing...
                }
            } while (reader.NextResult());
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException e) {
    register_error.Visible = true;

    if (e.Number == 2627) {
        // special handling for primary key/unique constraint violation
    }
    else {
        throw; // rethrow everything else
    }
}

register_username.Text = "";
register_password.Text = "";
register_mail.Text = "";
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

**Why bother with all of this?**

Number one, it truly prevents duplicates. It makes absolutely no sense to check for duplicates in client code if you want to prevent them in the database; simply prevent them from ever happening using a [primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys) or [unique constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints).

Another major benefit is that we save at least one trip to the database. The OP's original code has to query the database in order to check for duplicates; not only does this fail in the face of concurrent writers who use the same key value but it is also quite expensive in terms of time.

The [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) is used in order to encapsulate all inputs into a single "interface" that makes it easier to specify the contract between `C#` and `T-SQL`. It also has the side benefit of allowing us to insert many different users in a single transaction instead of making calls in some sort of loop.

Comment: While this is a good attempt, you're not checking if the user exists. And you have completely changed the design.

Comment: @CodingYoshi We don't need to check; the database constraint does that for us and bubbles up an exception to the caller. Of course I changed the design, the original attempt by the OP is extremely flawed and figured I'd show him (and any passers by) what a more proper implementation might look like.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 Oh, thank you for your effort actually! I am actually kinda new to this but I will be experimenting and testing with that for sure too!

Comment: You have no unique constraints so there will no exception. Even if there was, how would you know what caused the bubbled exception; it could be many reasons? Why do you think the design is flawed; perhaps make that part of your answer. Aside from hashing the password, not sure how OP's design is flawed. I am not saying I would do it  like that but I also won't say do it my way.

Comment: Also you're creating a random password which the user is not aware of at all.

Comment: @CodingYoshi A primary key **is** a unique constraint, which I placed on the `UserName` column. The unique constraint was left off of the `Email` column because one wasn't sure if the OP intended one or not; their code tells me that they are relatively inexperienced and so I figured I'd help nudge them in the right direction by "forgetting" it. The flaws are numerous and I tried to touch upon them in my "Why bother?" section; will try harder in a future edit...

Comment: @CodingYoshi That was meant as a demonstration of where each variable goes, I have since replaced it with the OP's original inputs (despite not knowing anything about them).

Comment: Making the username a primary key just to enforce uniqueness is not a good idea. It will be indexed and it is not a good index key. Your proposed solution has many flaws.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I made it the primary key because it is, by far, the most likely column to be filtered and joined on; in fact, only rare administrative actions would filter on any other column. There *is* an argument to be made for moving the primary key from `UserName` to `UserId` but we'd still have to replace it with a unique constraint (which is actually an index under the covers). Can you explain why exactly we don't want `UserName` to be indexed?